# Generation of a group with order of the product of primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

### Suppose that the order of a group $G$ is of the form $|G| = pqr$ where $p$, $q$, $r$ are primes, not necessarily distinct. Prove that $G$ can be generated by at most three elements of $G$.

One proposition from Lagrange's theorem that i thought could be used to apply this is:

Suppose that the order of the group G is a prime number. Thenonly has {$e$} and $G$ as subgroups, in particular $G = \langle g \rangle$ for any $g \neq e$ in $g$ is cyclic.

However this is only for when the order is a prime, which $pqr$ is not, So I'm kind of lost on how to show this is true.

Comment: Do you mean that there exists a set with no more than three elements that generates $G$?

Comment: @ajotatxe This is a past exam paper question, that i'm trying to wrap my head around, I just copied it word for word

Comment: Looks like you are not the only one working with this past exam: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241897/generators-of-a-group-with-prime-product-order

Comment: @RobinCarlier Yeah I've seen a few but with no success, it's an odd question

Comment: Do you have Cauchy's theorem in your toolbox? If $p$ is a prime number dividing $|G|$, then there exist an element of order $p$ in $G$.

Comment: I didn't know about that theorem, the closest one i have similar is: If $d$ is the power of a prime that divides |$G$| then there is a subgroup order $d$, but i doubt that is that helpful

Comment: Another suggestive (of at least one method of proof) way of stating this is that a group which cannot be generated by fewer than four elements has order the product of at least four primes (not necessarily distinct). Here we can replace four by any positive integer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a minimal set of generators: $\{a, b ,c , d \dots \}$

If $a$ is the identity, we discard it and the set is not minimal. If it generates the whole group we are done. The order of the subgroup generated by $a$ is $p, q, r, pq, pr \text{ or } qr$. It has order divisible by the product of at least one of the primes. Since they are primes, these are the only possible choices (Lagrange). Some of them may be equal.

Note that phrase "divisible by the product of at least one of the primes" - does that give you a clue as to how you might proceed?

> Now $a$ and $b$ together generate a subgoup. It is not the whole group (else we have a two generator set). If it has the same order as the group generated by $a$ it is the same subgroup and we discard $b$ from the set. Otherwise the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$ is larger than the subgroup generated by $a$, and contains it, and it must therefore have order divisible by at least two of the primes (and hence exactly two, since three is excluded).

You should be able to conclude and generalise from there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let $a \not = e$ be one generator. Then let $n_a$ be the order of $a$.
2. If $a$ generates the whole of $G$ then we are done. If $a$ does not generate the whole of $G$, let $b$ be **any** element of $G$ not generated by $a$. Then let $n_{ab}$ be the order of the group generated by $a,b$.
3. If $a$ and $b$ together generate the whole of $G$ then we are done. If $a$ and $b$ together do not generate the whole of $G$, let $c$ be **any** element of $G$ not generated by $a$ and $b$. Then let $n_{abc}$ be the order of the group generated by $a,b,c$ together.

Note that [assuming that $a$ and $b$ together do not generate the whole of $G$] the string of inequalities (A) $1 < n_a < n_{ab} < n_{abc} \le pqr$ hold. Furthermore, note that (B) $n_a|n_{ab}|n_{abc}|pqr$. As $p,q,r$ are all primes the only possibility for both (A) and (B) to hold simultaneously is if $n_{abc} = pqr$ [make sure you see this] and therefore $a,b,c$ together generate $G$.

So not only does a set of at most 3 elements generate $G$ but algorithmically it is also quite easy to find such a set.

---

What if $|G| = \prod_{i=1}^k p^{e_i}_i$? Can you give an upper bound for the number of generators in this case?